# Silent crash in Xamarin.Mac / Monomac?

Tags: multithreading, monomac, xamarin.mac

I need some advice with a random crash i'm facing in monomac, i think is related to how i use the UI, sometime i get an unknow selector error.

Here:

Stacktrace:

at  <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.NSApplicationMain (int,string[]) 
  at MonoMac.AppKit.NSApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00041] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/xamcore-lion-1.10-branch/834542f8/source/xamcore/src/AppKit/NSApplication.cs:105
  at Touring.MacOSX.MainClass.Main (string[]) [0x00005] in /Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/Main.cs:17
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

Debug info from gdb:

^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
^D
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
^D
quit
quExecuting commands in '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.rDRFXp'.
(lldb)  process attach --pid 4585
Process 4585 stopped
Executable module set to "/Users/starlingonzalez/Desktop/TouringProject/Touring/Touring.MacOSX/bin/Release/Touring.app/Contents/MacOS/Touring".
Architecture set to: i486-apple-macosx.
(lldb)  thread list
Process 4585 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x19905, 0x9a730fed libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 5, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #2: tid = 0x19911, 0x9a731992 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
  thread #3: tid = 0x19912, 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
  thread #4: tid = 0x19914, 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
  thread #5: tid = 0x19916, 0x9a72bfb6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
  thread #6: tid = 0x19917, 0x9a730a26 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__recvfrom + 10
  thread #7: tid = 0x19919, 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
  thread #8: tid = 0x1992d, 0x9a72bf7a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
(lldb)  thread backtrace all
* thread #1: tid = 0x19905, 0x9a730fed libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 5, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x9a730fed libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 5
    frame #1: 0x97e70ec5 libsystem_c.dylib`waitpid$UNIX2003 + 48
    frame #2: 0x00187319 Touring`mono_handle_native_sigsegv(signal=11, ctx=0x016eafe0) + 489 at mini-exceptions.c:2323
    frame #3: 0x001241a5 Touring`mono_arch_handle_altstack_exception(sigctx=0x016eafe0, fault_addr=0x37d8f5bb, stack_ovf=0) + 149 at exceptions-x86.c:1159
    frame #4: 0x001b5dbf Touring`mono_sigsegv_signal_handler(_dummy=11, info=0x016eafa0, context=0x016eafe0) + 415 at mini.c:6860
    frame #5: 0x963cbdeb libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 43

thread #2: tid = 0x19911, 0x9a731992 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.libdispatch-manager'
    frame #0: 0x9a731992 libsystem_kernel.dylib`kevent64 + 10
    frame #1: 0x974ef899 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_invoke + 238
    frame #2: 0x974ef532 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

thread #3: tid = 0x19912, 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x902e0dcf libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 372

thread #4: tid = 0x19914, 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x902e0dcf libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 372

thread #5: tid = 0x19916, 0x9a72bfb6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x9a72bfb6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00327fce Touring`mono_sem_wait(sem=<unavailable>, alertable=<unavailable>, sem=0x0042d700, alertable=1) + 30 at mono-semaphore.c:103
    frame #2: 0x00209eab Touring`finalizer_thread(unused=0x00000000) + 187 at gc.c:1077
    frame #3: 0x002e8395 Touring`start_wrapper [inlined] start_wrapper_internal(data=0x7be2fb40) + 523 at threads.c:660
    frame #4: 0x002e818a Touring`start_wrapper(data=0x7be2fb40) + 26 at threads.c:707
    frame #5: 0x00328cfd Touring`inner_start_thread(arg=0xbff36670) + 253 at mono-threads-posix.c:100
    frame #6: 0x902df5fb libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 144
    frame #7: 0x902df485 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 130

thread #6: tid = 0x19917, 0x9a730a26 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__recvfrom + 10
    frame #0: 0x9a730a26 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__recvfrom + 10
    frame #1: 0x97e710c9 libsystem_c.dylib`recv$UNIX2003 + 54
    frame #2: 0x00100480 Touring`socket_transport_recv(buf=0xb039af2d, len=11) + 160 at debugger-agent.c:1131
    frame #3: 0x000fc4bb Touring`debugger_thread(arg=0x00000000) + 22267 at debugger-agent.c:1557
    frame #4: 0x00328cfd Touring`inner_start_thread(arg=0xbff36680) + 253 at mono-threads-posix.c:100
    frame #5: 0x902df5fb libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 144
    frame #6: 0x902df485 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 130

thread #7: tid = 0x19919, 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #0: 0x9a731046 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__workq_kernreturn + 10
    frame #1: 0x902e0dcf libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 372

thread #8: tid = 0x1992d, 0x9a72bf7a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x9a72bf7a libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x9a72b16c libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg + 68
    frame #2: 0x9a577bf9 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 169
    frame #3: 0x9a5771d1 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1393
    frame #4: 0x9a5769ea CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
    frame #5: 0x9a57684b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #6: 0x90c95b88 AppKit`_NSEventThread + 283
    frame #7: 0x902df5fb libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 144
    frame #8: 0x902df485 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 130
(lldb)  detach
Detaching from process 4585
(lldb)  quit

Comment: Please post a minimal working code which reproducibly shows the above error

Comment: Hi @nodakai, after checking a few options on the project setting, i notice that in the build -> general the the compile target was on Executable, so i change it to Executable with GUI, also i made some improvement to the Collections of objects such List, IEnumerable, etc...

After i made those changes everything start working better, but i still receive crashes on some screen, i notice that the method GetObjectValue in TableViewSource get called more than once when bind and also when i made a click on a row. there's a way to improve the performance of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figure it out after many try and catch here and there, that you can put in the constructor of your AppDelegate.cs class the following:

```
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) => {
                Exception GivenException = (Exception) e.ExceptionObject;
                Console.WriteLine( GivenException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine( GivenException.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine("Runtime terminating: {0}", e.IsTerminating);
            };
```

This will not avoid the app for terminate but at least you will know exactly where to look and fix the issues.

Just dropped here in case somebody is having same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes crashes like this can be due to bugs in the bindings. Try holding on to a c# reference to the screens / UI elements that are associated with the crash. If this fixes the issue, file a bug:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com

with details.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Mono 3.6. It's fixed a lot of threading issues, including issues with creating large numebrs of shortlived threads.